# Android Linkedin SDK DeepLink automatically crash

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am trying to "Deeplink" to some user profile on my Android application
but the app always reacts the same way. It opens the offical Linkedin Application, which crashes immediatly, and then it doesn't enter in the callback (onDeepLinkError)...

I tried both ***openCurrentProfile*** and ***openOtherProfile*** methods...
My session is valid, and I am authenticated, everything's good on that side.

Here is my piece of code :

```
DeepLinkHelper deepLinkHelper = new DeepLinkHelper();
deepLinkHelper.openCurrentProfile(getActivity(), new DeepLinkListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDeepLinkSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeepLinkError(LIDeepLinkError error) {
        Log.e("ERROR", error.toString());
    }
});
```

**EDIT :** It seems to crash only on my smartphone, I ran the app on a friend device, and I works properly... Any ideas would be extremely apprieciated :D

Comment: Provide us the logcat trace or nobody will be able to help you

Comment: As I said, the onDeepLinkError callback is never called so I can't print the error log... My app just crashes and that's all.

Comment: If it crashes, then there is definitely an error log. It may not come from your code, but maybe from an internal API of the SDK you're using. Paste the logcat of the crash you're experiencing